# Angular *ngFor : How to display two adjacent values in the same iteration?

Tags: angular

Got an array : [A,B,C,D]

I want to display something like this :

### From A to B

### From C to D

How i can achieve this using *ngFor in Angular ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal Reproducible Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Abhishek : you ve downgraded the question because you doesnt understand it ? Im sorry for u but nothing else was needed to add. Short and simple is better.

Comment: You could have mentioned what you have tried or posted a minimal reproducible example where you were facing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `index` and `even` [local variables](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) of the `*ngFor` directive. Try the following

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index; let even=even">
  <ng-container *ngIf="even">
    {{ items[i] }} {{ items[i+1] }}
    <br/>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thanks dude have a big day.